# extra developer-account for google console

Tags: android, account, google-play-console

I've made two apps for different clients and now i want to add them both to my gmail account.
The two clients has nothing to do with eachother and therefore i want each of them to be represented by them selves. I just cant find any place where i can add an extra account to my own developer account.
Do i really need to make an account for each client? And then also make the purchase-verification on each account afterwards?

Both apps are free apps. They are used to sell food in a cantina.
Thanks
/Wel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make a separate account for each client. You don't have to, but it is the best way to do what is right for the client. That way there aren't confusing "also by this developer" messages pointing to other clients.

Nothing stops you linking your personal account as a user on both accounts.